# change values of a column

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I need to change values of a column in EXCEL 2010 on Win 7.

This the macro. But, it only works for one cell even though I selected a column with 1000 tows.

```
 Sub Change0to1()
    SelectedRange = Selection.Rows.Count
    ActiveCell.Select
    For i = 1 To SelectedRange
        If ActiveCell.Value = 0 Then
           ActiveCell.Value = 1
        End If
    Next i
 End Sub
```

Any help would be apprecaited.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
Sub Change0to1()
   For i = 1 To Selection.Cells.Count
       If Selection(i).Value = 0 Then
          Selection(i).Value = 1
       End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

This iterates through all the cells in the selection so it doesn't matter whether they are in a row and it doesn't matter which of the selected cells is the active cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Sub Change0to1()
    Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Selection
        If c.Value = 0 Then c.Value = 1
    Next c
End Sub
```

Note, that `For Each` loop is faster than `For i = ..`